# Salt stack state management and continuous deployment

Tags: salt-stack

The goal I want to achieve is to manage the state of a salt deployment from a git repo only, Imagine a repo containing the salt states and several minions ( which can be defined in the git pipeline variables ). After each commit on the master branch CI pipeline should run and apply the new states to the minions. Any pointers to how I can achieve this is appreciated.

Note. 1. the pipeline is my mind is Gitlab runners

Note. 2. the SSH keys are shared by the runner variables too

this is just an idea I'm new to salt stack and most of examples I saw are based on a live salt master.

Comment: https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/tutorials/gitfs.html

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/saltstack/comments/i2xk4q/saltstack_with_gitlab_cicd/